# grouping/joining collinear segments in an image

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation, hough-transform

I am working on road extraction from the aerial images. I applied Hough-Line transformation on the binary image

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,rho=1,theta=np.pi/180, threshold=10,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=5,maxLineGap=3)
```

As a result I got the segments, I want to join these segments. I could think of grouping the collinear segments and fitting a center-line, But I couldn't figure out how can I group the segments based on there proximity/connectivity, or is there anyother approach to join collinear segments?
[image][image][image]

Comment: Have you tried to increase the maxLineGap parameter?

Comment: By increasing maxLineGap, it gives straight lines instead the following the curvature of road.